# Error Migrating SQL Server Database to Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server

So I am completely new to .Net Core development, and was given a codebase that I am trying to host on Microsoft Azure. I have the local database file (.mdf) in SQL Server Management Studio, and am trying to deploy it to an Azure Database, However it keeps failing during migration and giving me this issue

> Error SQL71627: The element User: [ISOCENTRIC\Administrator] has property >AuthenticationType set to a value that is not supported in Microsoft Azure SQL >Database v12.
>   (Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac)

However, when I `SELECT * FROM master.sys.database_principals;` and it dumps the db users list, the "ISOCENTRIC\Administrator" user does not appear in that list, so I cannot find a way to drop it from the DB. Is there something I am missing regarding the location of this user and how I can drop it from the db so I can migrate to Azure?

p.s. This is my first post on here so please let me know if I should make any changes to adhere to correct formatting on this forum.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the database users can't be migrated to Azure SQL DB because they are Windows users. You'll need to drop those users before you deploy this database to Azure SQL DB.

You can always backup and restore a copy of this database, remove the users, and then deploy that one to Azure SQL Db.

Comment: I am not able to find the users to drop them. When I do a dump of users in the db, that particular does not show up

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that my query to dump the database users was incorrect, and was able to find and drop the user causing the issue.